# Assigning category, collision and contact bit mask to reference nodes in code

Tags: swift, xcode, collision-detection, scenekit

I have a level based game, so I am using the Xcode Scene Editor for level creation, but am having troubles detecting collision between objects, that were created in separate scenes and dragged in game scenes as reference nodes.

It seems that if I try to create the physics body of an object, that is used as a reference node in that .scn file where I created it, that physics body is not being referenced to nodes in the game scene, but the properties that were created directly in Scene Editor are.

If I try and set the physics body of each node that is actually a reference node via code, it does set it (the physics body is not nil), but the collision is not detected.

This is the code, where I set the physics bodies:

```
    // player (I want to be notified when player collides with any walls)
    playerNode = level1Scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("playerNode", recursively: true)!
    playerNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape: nil)
    playerNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    playerNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player.rawValue
    playerNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall.rawValue
    playerNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall.rawValue

    //wall from separate .scn file
    let wallScene = SCNScene(named: "wallObject.scn")
    let wall = wallScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("wall", recursively: true)!
    wall.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Kinematic, shape: nil)
    wall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall.rawValue
    wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player.rawValue
    wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player.rawValue

    // walls that are reference nodes of the wall and are located in game scene 
    let wall2 = level1Scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("wallObject reference", recursively: true)!
    wall2.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Kinematic, shape: nil)
    wall2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall.rawValue
    wall2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player.rawValue
    wall2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player.rawValue
    print(wall2.physicsBody!) // prints <SCNPhysicsBody: 0x7fe5f9dc75a0>
```

I am not contacted about any contacts, nor does the player physically collide with any wall on contact. I have conformed the class to the  `SCNPhysicsContactDelegate` protocol:

```
extension GameViewController: SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {
    func physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBeginContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
        playerNode.physicsBody?.velocity = SCNVector3Zero
        print("player and wall collided")
    }
}
```

and set the contact delegate to my game scene:

```
level1Scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

I have been trying to get this to work for two days now, with no success. When I was working with Sprite Kit, I could almost always find relevant posts about my problem and even when posting my question, I would get an answer. But Scene Kit is not as popular I guess and I can't find anything.

If you do know where I am wrong or how the collision could be detected in code, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I cobbled together an example loosely based on the code you posted up, the only 'problem' is that it worked, in that the contact delegate is successfully called. The player geometry in this case is the SceneKit spaceship, and the wall2 is a SCNBox added into the other scene then dragged into the ship scene from Finder. I've included gravity, so the ship just falls onto the wall.

Do the objects bounce off each other, and it's just that your contact delegate isn't called? Or do the objects pass through each other. I'm also wondering how you move the player object to cause the contact?

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit

let colors = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.brownColor(), UIColor.cyanColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.blueColor()]

enum PhysicsCategory:Int {
    case Player = 2
    case Wall = 4
}

extension GameViewController: SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {

    func physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBeginContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
        playerNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = colors[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))]
        print("player and wall collided")
    }
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerNode:SCNNode!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a new scene
        //let scene = SCNScene()
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

        //playerNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0))
        playerNode = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("ship", recursively: true)!
        playerNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
        playerNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape: nil)
        playerNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        playerNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player.rawValue
        playerNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall.rawValue
        playerNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall.rawValue

        initPlayer()
        //scene.rootNode.addChildNode(playerNode)

        //let wall = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 20, height: 0.25, length: 20, chamferRadius: 0))
        let wallScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/wallObject.scn")
        let wall = wallScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("wall", recursively: true)!
        wall.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Kinematic, shape: nil)
        wall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall.rawValue
        wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player.rawValue
        wall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player.rawValue
        //scene.rootNode.addChildNode(wall)

        let wall2 = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("wallObject reference", recursively: true)!
        wall2.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Kinematic, shape: nil)
        wall2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall.rawValue
        wall2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player.rawValue
        wall2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player.rawValue


        scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
        scnView.playing = true
        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
        scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        scnView.showsStatistics = true
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        // add a tap gesture recognizer
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func handleTap(gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        initPlayer()
    }

    func initPlayer() {
        playerNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 12, 0)
        playerNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(Float(drand48() * M_PI/2), Float(drand48() * M_PI/2), Float(drand48() * M_PI/2))
        playerNode.physicsBody?.velocity = SCNVector3Zero
        playerNode.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = SCNVector4Zero
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured what the problem was. I have a lot of wall reference node and they all have the same name, so I was setting physics body on just one of them and the rest were left without it. I solved the problem by enumerating all child nodes and setting those properties on ones with this name, but I was skeptical if this is an okay way of doing it. I have 200 walls, so when running the loop where I set the physics body for each of them, the same thing is repeated 200 times. Would it be better if I set the wall's physics body directly for the wall in the file from where it is being referenced?

Comment: I can't see it impacting performance in any great way. I'd see it more as a matter of convenience. Setting these parameters in the source scn file would mean all walls have the same properties, whereas setting them up in code would give you some flexibility. Maybe you want some walls to have more bounce than others, or belong to a different collision category... Still it would make sense to include some default physics properties.